# How to find who updated stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I know that I can find the last modified date of a stored procedure in sys.objects tables in SQL Server 2012. Is there any way I can find who updated it?

Comment: [Who modified SP](http://serverfault.com/questions/258111/finding-out-who-has-modified-a-stored-procedure-on-sql-server)

Comment: Also see [SQL Server Schema Auditing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470301/sql-server-schema-auditing).